# require_once for bash, but how to for older bash and POSIX-shell?

Tags: bash, posix, require-once

Inspired by the Php `require_once` I figured how it could be implemented for modern Bash with associative arrays here:

`a.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -gAi __REQUIRES

require_once() {
  for p; do
    r=$(readlink --canonicalize-existing "$p")
    # shellcheck disable=SC1090 # Dynamic source
    [[ -r "$r" && 1 -ne "${__REQUIRES[$r]}" ]] && __REQUIRES[$r]=1 && . "$r"
  done
}

require_once ./b.sh
require_once ./b.sh

hello
```

`b.sh`

```sh
hello() {
  printf 'I am the hello function in b.sh.\n'
}
```

This works as intended:

1. Get the real path of the `source`.
2. Check it is readable, check it is not already loaded by looking-up the global associative array key.
3. If so, register it in the global associative array and source it.

Now I am still wondering how to:

1. Get the real path of the source in a more portable/standard way not depending on Linux Gnu Tools?
2. Have it work with older Bash like 3.2
3. Have it work with POSIX-shell grammar without array.

Comment: Also check https://loader.sourceforge.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get the real path of the source in a more portable/standard way not depending on Linux Gnu Tools?

`readlink -f` is available on Busybox. Do `readlink` after checking that the path exists.

Anyway, https://www.google.com/search?q=readlink+POSIX -> https://medium.com/mkdir-awesome/posix-alternatives-for-readlink-21a4bfe0455c , https://github.com/ko1nksm/readlinkf .

> Have it work with older Bash like 3.2
>
> Have it work with POSIX-shell grammar without array.

POSIX does not like newlines in filenames anyway, so just store files as lines:

```
__REQUIRES=""
if ! printf "%s" "$__REQUIRES" | grep -Fq "$r"; then
   __REQUIRES="$__REQUIRES""$r
"
   . "$r"
fi
```

Or maybe use case so that you do not `fork`:

```
__REQUIRES="
"
case "$__REQUIRES" in
*"
$r
"*) ;;
*) 
    __REQUIRES="$__REQUIRES""$r
"
    . "$r"
    ;;
esac
```

If you want to handle newlines in filenames, convert filename via `xxd` or `od` (both are available on Busybox, `od` is POSIX) and store hex representation of filenames as lines in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

bash 3.2 does not implement associative arrays, so we could create individual "required" variable names for each script.

Don't forget that `readlink -e` or `-f` *fails* if the symlink is broken, so let's work that into the function.

MacOS `readlink` does not have a "canonicalize" option at all, so I don't how this can be made portable.

Perhaps this: works on my Mac with GNU readlink installed with homebrew.

```sh
require_once() {
    local script canonical varname val
    for script; do
        if canonical=$(readlink -f -- "$script") && [[ -r "$canonical" ]]; then
            varname=$(printf '__REQUIRED__%s' "${canonical//[^[:alnum:]]/__}")
            val=$(eval "echo \$$varname")
            if [[ -z $val ]]; then
                eval "$varname=1"
                . "$canonical"
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIX-shell grammar method using symbolic links in temp directory as already required source markers:

`a.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

unset __REQUIRES;
trap 'rm -fr -- "$__REQUIRES"' EXIT INT
__REQUIRES=$(mktemp -d)

require_once() {
  for p; do
    # Path is readable or continue
    [ -r "$p" ] || continue

    # Get real path
    r=$(readlink -f -- "$p")

    # New real path in __REQUIRES temp dir
    nr="$__REQUIRES$r"

    # If path __REQUIRES temp dir exists, file is already sourced
    [ -r "$nr" ] && continue

    # Make equivalent path for file in __REQUIRES temp dir
    mkdir -p -- "${nr%/*}"

    # Create symbolic link to __REQUIRES temp dir
    ln -sf -- "$r" "$nr"

    # shellcheck disable=SC1090 # Dynamic source
    . "$r"
  done
}

counter=0

require_once ./b.sh
require_once ./b.sh

hello
printf 'counter=%d\n' "$counter"
```

`b.sh`

```sh
counter=$((counter + 1))

hello() {
  printf 'I am the hello function in b.sh.\n'
}
```